# Customize properties sheet of a BeanNode in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have consulted the [Node API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-nodes/org/openide/nodes/Sheet.html), and some examples like [HERE](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.netbeans.modules.openide.devel/52315).
My problem is to customize the `properties` sheet of a `BeanNode` so that I hide the "Properties" and create my own one.

For that, usuallay I have to override `createSheet()` method, and this is my code (in fact I want to show only the "`Expert`" sheet.

```
 @Override
    protected Sheet createSheet() {
        Sheet sheet = super.createSheet();
       Sheet.Set set = Sheet.createExpertSet();

        TUser user = getLookup().lookup(TUser.class);
        try {
            Property loginProp = new PropertySupport.Reflection(user, String.class, "getLogin", null);

            loginProp.setName("Login");

            set.put(loginProp);

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            ErrorManager.getDefault();
        }

        sheet.remove(Sheet.PROPERTIES);
        sheet.put(set);

        return sheet;
    }
```

What I got is: 
[image: Properties sheet]

How can I hide `Properties` sheet and show only the `Expert` one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abviously, your node must extend AbstractNode not BeanNode